Group theory - Transfer function and commutator
I'm stuck with this one:
Let $J$ normal in $H$, $H$ normal in $G$, with $G/H$ finite and $H/J$ abelian. Let $\operatorname{tr}$ be the transfer $G \to H/J$ and let $\operatorname{Im}\operatorname{tr} = I/J$, where $J \le I \le H$. Then $[G, I] \le J$.
I can't do better than $\operatorname{tr}([g,i])=J$. I don't see how to use the fact that $H$ is normal. Maybe a small hint on what to look at.
Regards

Here is a MathJax tutorial.

We need to check that ${\rm tr}(g) = f{\rm tr}(g)f^{-1}$ for all $f,g \in G$.
Let $T$ be a (right) transversal of $H$ in $G$. Then, the normality of $H$ in $G$ implies that $\{ft : t \in T\}$ is also a transversal of $H$ in $G$.
Now, writing $\overline{g}$ for the coset representative of $g \in G$ (that is, the unique element in $T \cap Hg$), we have
$${\rm tr}(g) = \prod_{t \in T}tg\overline{tg}^{-1}J,$$
and
$$f{\rm tr}(g)f^{-1} = \prod_{t \in T}ftg\overline{tg}^{-1}f^{-1}J= \prod_{t \in T}ftg(f\overline{tg})^{-1}J = \prod_{t \in T}ftg(\overline{ftg})^{-1}J = {\rm tr}(g)$$
as required.
